# Web-api: property names for Xml and Json

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

Hej, I have a web-api controller (written in c#) which returns either xml or json (as desired) according to the request. Now I have a requirement that the names of the properties in the returned objects are different, depending on whether it is Json or Xml which is bring returned. Is this possible?

For example, method "GetAddress" returns an "Address" object, with properties like "StreetName", "HouseNumber", "ZipCode"...

Now I want property names for Json like "Street" (without "Name" at all), and for Xml like "street_name", and similar differences for other properties.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 3):

found out I can use 2 attributes on my properties: one to name them for Json, and one to name them for Xml. For example:

```
    [DataMember(Name = "street_name")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Street")]
    public string StreetName{ get; set; }
```

(and also a [DataContract] attribute on the class itself).